# How to set code versions activity in Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

Versions 1 to 3 of my app in Google Play have minSdkVersion = 15.

Then, when I published version 4, I changed minSdk to 16. Google Play Console automatically kept version 3 active for users with Android API = 15, with was quite sensible.

In version 57 I chagned minSdk once again, and set it to 26. I expected version 56 (with minSdk = 16) would be still active for users with Android API between 16 and 25. But it didn't happen and version 56 was deactivated automatically.

Now, there  are two code versions active:

- version 3 for users with Android API < 26
- version 57 for users with Android API >= 26

My aim is to have version 56 available for users with Android API from 16 to 25, but I have no idea how to change activity of code versions in Google Play Console. Is it even possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

(*I never though PlayStore keeps active an old version for very old SDK users...it's strange Google does it because if you release a newer version it should be take in count about old users **in your new code** and not by a complete old and separated version.*)

At this time you can't change something of previous releases. Unfortunately PlayStore doesn't more accept updates that targets SDK<26 so the only think you can do is take in count SDK between 16 and 25 in your code while targetting 26+.